# Is there another way to get value from object method into object variable

Tags: python, oop, variables, methods

I made code that goes like this

```
class Dog():
    def breed():
        return "rottwiller"

    def __init__(self, name, age, breed=breed()):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.breed = breed
```

Is there another way to achieve "self.breed" value instead of breed=breed(), but through function method as well.

for example something similar to this( I have tried out this that does not work):

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.breed = breed()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: What's the point of the `breed` function anyway? You'll get more useful responses if you explain what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: @Aran-Fey English is not my frist language, i used this code so it would be clear. Purpuse is that i want to have variable in a class that will be created when i initiallise instance with value that will get trought function but without my input. 

i am not sure if i am making sense here. So, i will parse some arguments in instance and object will use that argument to create variablas based on methods i create inside object.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the code posted.

1. The `breed` method is overwritten in `__init__` method as you set the `breed` attribute. So the method should be renamed.
2. The `breed` method needs to specify the first argument `self`.

   class Dog:
       def get_breed(self):
           return "rottwiller"

   ```
   def __init__(self, name, age):
       self.name = name
       self.age = age
       self.breed = self.get_breed()
   ```

Comment: This code doesn't even run if you try and create an instance of the class

Comment: I have tried out that does not work:

   self.breed = self.breed()
  TypeError: breed() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: @user3483203 What code? Mine? it does. Second one shows error that i quoted

"    self.breed = self.breed()
TypeError: breed() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the code so that it now works by changing the name of the method to `get_breed` so it does not conflict with the attribute name you'd like to user, and adding the required `self` argument to the `get_breed` method.

Comment: I just verified that this code works: `Dog("a", "b").breed`
'rottwiller'

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't name an attribute and a method the same thing. That being said, my suspicions for why you are asking this question tell me I should point you towards the `@property` decorator.

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, name, age, breed):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self._breed = breed

    @property
    def breed(self):
        return self._breed
```

This is overkill for your example, but if you have a `Dog` class and a specific breed, I imagine you are thinking about subclasses and possibly more complicated things than you are doing here. Essentially, the `@property` decorator will allow you to access `breed` as an attribute, and will return the value of the call to the function you define under it by the same name.

Comment: You need to add `self` to the breed property for this to work.

Comment: @MatthewStory I realized what you meant. I recommend pressing the "edit" button instead of the "downvote" button for simple mistakes on answers that you notice before their author.

Comment: i removed my downvote when the code worked, my answer was also downvoted for the same reason ... :shrug:

Comment: @MladenMODD this answer and the one you accepted do different things and have different method signatures for `__init__`. I'm still not sure what your use case is

Comment: Use case is bit more complex but my object will take argument as url address and get some data from that address (generate it trought methods), and after that i want to send that generated data to DB as object_name.variable_name

For example
website[0].title_of_a_website

i am looking for various ways to achieve that.

Comment: Btw whats with downvotes? I think all the answers and question are totally okay. 
Who and why is downvoting?